# AngularJS select required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm having some issues with setting up the validation for a select. the code reads like

HTML

```
<form name="customerForm" novalidate="novalidate" data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <li class="has-error" data-ng-if="customerForm.country.$error.required">
        {{ 'CountryRequired' | translate }}
    </li>

    <label for="ddlCountries">{{ 'Country' | translate }}</label>
    <select id="ddlCountries" name="country" class="form-control"
        data-ng-model="selectedCountry"
        data-ng-options="option.text for option in countries track by option.id"
        data-ng-change="countryChange()" required="required">
        <option value="" selected="selected">{{ 'SelectCountry' | translate }}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JS Controller

```
$scope.countries = [];
countryService.getCountries().then(function (results) {
    $scope.countries = results.data;
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error.data.message);
});

$scope.$watch('customer.country', function (id) {
    // Select the value on the dropdown list
    $scope.selectedCountry = { id: id };
});

$scope.countryChange = function () {
    $scope.customer.country = $scope.selectedCountry.id;
};

$scope.submit = function () {
    if ($scope.customerForm.$valid) {
        customerService.postCustomerForm($scope.customer).success(
            function (data, status, headers, config) {
                /*success callback*/
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Submitting form failed!");
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid fields");
    }
};
```

I've tried different things like setting `selected="selected"` on the `select` but didn't work. Also tried `required` and `ng-required` without luck.

Am I missing something or doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reset select model so original one you defined is replaced with a new one. Look at this piece of code:

```
$scope.$watch('customer.country', function(id) {
    $scope.selectedCountry = {id: id};
});
```

In this code you overwrite `$scope.selectedCountry` with *totally new object*, so the model which has been used for setting up form validation is destroyed and new validation is never build.

In your case you can update `selectedCountry` model like this:

```
$scope.$watch('customer.country', function(id) {
    if (id) {
        $scope.selectedCountry.id = id;
    }
});
```

But better, remove wather all together, you don't need it since you have `ngChange` directive, where you can update `selectedCountry.id`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/CXDRdRYxZn38FnanOqid?p=preview

Comment: How would you do then the selected value? If I use the the value from `customer.country` after I select a value the int changes to an object there may be a better way than the $watch and the change function

Comment: If you need watch then use it, just don't reassign entire model object.